# How do I install miku miku dance?

Tags: software-installation

So I have Ubuntu quantal quetzal and wish to install [MMD/Miku Miku Dance](http://www.geocities.jp/higuchuu4/index_e.htm). Does anyone knows how to run it in Ubuntu?

Comment: What is "MMD/Miku Miku Dance"? Where did you find it?

Comment: @terdon MMD is a program to create choreography of Vocaloids, which are in turn virtual singers. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MikuMikuDance maker page http://www.geocities.jp/higuchuu4/index_e.htm

Comment: @user264654 you might want to upgrade 12.10 to 14.04 when the later comes out or downgrade to 12.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MikuMikuDance is a Windows only software, so it's not supposed to work on Linux. You can use Wine [instead to make it work](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=24292). Once you download the MMD (Multi Model Edition) from [the creator](http://www.geocities.jp/higuchuu4/index_e.htm), install wine and winetricks:

```
sudo apt-get install wine winetricks
```

Install the Visual C++ 2005 runtime using winetricks:

```
winetricks vcrun2005
```

Download the program and unzip it:

```
wget http://www.geocities.jp/higuchuu4/pict/MikuMikuDanceE_v524.zip
unzip MikuMikuDanceE_v524.zip
```

Now run it:

```
cd MikuMikuDance_*
wine MikuMikuDance.exe
```

Have fun!